# Is it possible to check mydomain API responses through Pingdom?

Tags: pingdom

Q: Is there a way to configure Pingdom to check results from mydomain's API?

The API would consist of multiple GET requests. If so how can I approach this. Uptime Check and Transactional check don't seem to offer what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be surprised if you can't do this with Pingdom. The options tab of the http check allows you to submit post requests to an API, with the appropriate headers set.

This article touches on that http://royal.pingdom.com/2016/02/19/make-the-most-of-your-http-check-best-practice-for-optional-settings/

Maybe you could explain further what you need to achieve?